# File types supported by imreadmulti() function in Opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv

I was trying to load multipage image file formats in Opencv by *imreadmulti()* function. Apart from .Tiff files, what are the other file types supported by imreadmulti()?

I tried loading Pdf, Docx, and Dicom files too with imreadmulti(), as it accepts multipage file types, according to the official documentation. But they didn't work. Could somebody help me know the other file types supported by imreadmulti().

Answer (score 1):

BMP (Windows bitmap)

DIB (Device-independent bitmap)

JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group)

JPG (Joint Photographic Experts Group)

JP2 (JPEG 2000)

PNG (Portable Network Graphics)

PBM (Portable bitmap)

PGM (Portable graymap)

PPM (Portable pixmap)

SR (Sun raster)

RAS (Sun raster)

TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)

TIF (Tagged Image File Format)

EXR (OpenEXR)

JXR (JPEG XR)

PFM (Portable float map)

PDS (NASA Planetary Data System)

PFM (Portable float map)

VIFF (Khoros Visualization image file format)

XBM (X11 bitmap)

XPM (X11 pixmap)

DDS (DirectDraw Surface)

EIS (Encapsulated image file)

MNG (Multiple-image Network Graphics)

WEBP

HEIF

HEIC

AVIF

**Note**

note that some of the file types given below may require additional libraries or codecs to be installed on your system in order to be read by OpenCV. They're:

SGI (Silicon Graphics Image)

CUR (Windows cursor)

ICO (Windows icon)

GIF (Graphics Interchange Format)

DJVU (DjVu image format)

PDF (Portable Document Format)

WMF (Windows Metafile)

EMF (Enhanced Metafile)

Comment: This answer is partially correct as imreadmulti() function is unable to load SR, RAS, JXR, HEIF, HEIC, AVIF etc